# Unable to get my App id for parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using www.parse.com for an xcode project. Since they do not allow new sign ups, so how do I get my application id for the following code in order to use their services:

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "YOUR_APP_ID"
        $0.server = "http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse"
    }
 Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)
```

Comment: They did open source all of their code if I remember correctly.  So in order to use their framework now (since you can't sign up) you would need to set up your own web server with their source code installed and running.  Otherwise no, there is no way of getting an App ID from them.

Comment: Found it: https://youtu.be/mup6Da41IjQ